# Vanity URL redirecting to tracking url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.myvanityurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myprimaryurl.com?utm_source=myvanityurl.com&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=general [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myprimaryurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myprimaryurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#Remove index.php from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically I want this file to acheive 4 things:

1. Redirect myvanityurl.com to the tracking url
2. Redirect any parked domains to myprimaryurl.com
3. Force all domains to use HTTP
4. Remove index.php from the url

All of these work as expected except for rule 1. myvanityurl.com is redirecting to https://www.myprimaryurl.com but the query string paramaters are missing from the url. Would appreciate any advice as to why this is not working.

Comment: What query string parameters are missing – the ones you placed there yourself in the rewrite substitution, or any ones that were present on the _original_ request? If the latter, you’ll want to use the flag `QSA`. If the former – debug what is going on. Check via your browser’s debug tools, network panel, what requests your browser makes. Perhaps it makes the initial one including the query string parameters you want, but then gets redirected again by your other rules or something like that.

Comment: The parameters missing are the ones I put there myself in the redirect url. myvanityurl.com should redirect to https://www.myprimaryurl.com?utm_source=myvanityurl.com&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=general but instead it gets redirected to just https://www.myprimaryurl.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your first rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myvanityurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myprimaryurl.com/$1?utm_source=myvanityurl.com&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=general [R=301,L,NE]
```

i.e remove starting `DOT` from `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable's pattern and use `$1` in target URL.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Clearing the cache and removing the DOT appears to have solved this.